# Animation instances aren't cleaned up

Tags: kivy

## Enviroment

- Python 3.6.3
- Kivy master
- OS: Linux Mint 18.2(based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

## Code

Hi, I'm writing unittest of `kivy.animation`. When I ran the code below

```python3
import unittest
from time import time, sleep
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock


class AnimationTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    SLEEP_DURATION = .3
    TIMES = 2

    def sleep(self, t):
        start = time()
        while time() < start + t:
            sleep(.01)
            Clock.tick()

    def test_animation(self):
        for index in range(self.TIMES):
            print('----------------------------------')
            with self.subTest(index=index):
                w = Widget()
                a = Animation(x=100, d=.2)
                print('a:', a)
                a.start(w)
                self.sleep(self.SLEEP_DURATION)
                print('instances_:', Animation._instances)
                self.assertEqual(len(Animation._instances), 0)
```

output is

```
----------------------------------
a: <kivy.animation.Animation object at 0x7f0afb31c660>
instances_: set()
----------------------------------
a: <kivy.animation.Animation object at 0x7f0afc20b180>
instances_: {<kivy.animation.Animation object at 0x7f0afc20b250>, <kivy.animation.Animation object at 0x7f0afb31c660>}

 ======================================================================
 FAIL: test_animation (kivy.tests.test_animations.AnimationTestCase) (index=1)
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/tmp/firefox/kivy/kivy/tests/test_animations.py", line 34, in test_animation
     self.assertEqual(len(Animation._instances), 0)
 AssertionError: 2 != 0

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Ran 1 test in 0.822s

 FAILED (failures=1)
```

Either of

- Increase SLEEP_DURATION (for example `SLEEP_DURATION = 2`) or
- `TIMES = 1`

will fix this error.

## Is this correct behavior or bug?

Comment: If this is not a bug, can you explain why program behave like that?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error is `kivy.modules.inspector`.

After I removed this line from `config.ini`,

```
[modules]
inspector =     # <= remove this line
```

the program behave how I expect. Seems like `ScrollView` inside `inspector` creates `Animation` internally, and it makes my test fails.